# Why didn't they show us what happened outside the Avengers center?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

How did

> the "dusted" people come back after Hulk's snap?

I mean the process itself. Does the

> dust just re-assemble into people? Even though it would have spread everywhere or did the people just pop into existence where they died?

Comment: Not everything needs to be shown. If they'd had a sequence where people were undusted, it would have taken away from the portal sequence where Thanos' enemies all turn up

Answer (score 2):

> did the people just pop into existence where they died?

We can definitely tell that people come back in the same location (relative to whatever planet they were on, presumably) — we see at least Titan and Wakanda in the background of the relevant portals for the characters who were dusted there.

Sadly, we don't know what that looks like. But hey, maybe we'll see that in future MCU movies somehow.

#### Thrilling Phase 4 updates!

Yup, people pretty much just re-assemble in place, in a reverse-dusting kind of effect. We see this happen to various unnamed characters in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, and to

> Monica Rambeau, daughter of Maria Rambeau from *Captain Marvel*, in *WandaVision*.

We even kind of get to see this from the perspective of a character who went through it in *Hawkeye*, when

> Yelena Belova

goes to the bathroom and doesn’t come out for five years.